# How to find .jpg file size without headers?

Tags: python, image-processing, compression, jpeg, jpeg2000

I need to find size of a `.jpg` file without its header (or metadata). How can I do that?

I guess JPEG data contains two parts:

1. Header or metadata which is not related to image and has information about subsampling values or quantization table
2. Main data which is result of compressing the image and depends on image. For a reason, I just care about **size of main data**. How can I get the size (in bytes)?

Comment: Please try to explain what you actually have. And why you only have part of the image. It doesn't make much sense at the moment.

Comment: Hello @MarkSetchell. I'm researching on a new method for compression which depends on the size of main data. So we can say I have `img.jpg` and I need size of its main data. you need more info?

Comment: You'll need to read up on JFIF and EXIF formats and decide which regions you consider "main data" and calculate it yourself.

Comment: This could be useful: https://pypi.org/project/exif-delete/

Comment: @amin I suggest you to do some research, and be more specific. You may read about JPEG [Syntax and structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure) in Wikipedia. It looks like you are looking for the size of the **SOS** payload. Also, remove the jpeg2000 tag, because it doesn't seem to be related to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx for comments. As Anon Coward said I've found this useful image which shows different parts of a JPEG file:
[image: JPEG structure]

I wanted length of `Image Data` so I need to find `0xFF 0xDA` and count bytes from there, then subtract 16 from it. Here is the code:

```py
def get_JPEG_size(file_path):
  total_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)

  with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    s = f.read()
  
  header_size = s.find(b'\xff\xda')
  if header_size == -1:
    print("`FF DA` not found!")
    return 0
  header_size += (2 + 12) + 2
  
  data_size = total_size - header_size

  return data_size
```